# iMac System Preferences

Tags: macos, icloud, preferences

When I click the apple symbol and select System Preferences it takes me an iCloud page.

I want to view the settings on my printer.  Why is this happening and how can I correct it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's helpful if you provide us the version of macOS you're running and a screen shot of what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to me recently and I believe it is Apple reminding you (over and over and over and over....) to set up two factor authentication in iCloud. On my Mac (High Sierra 10.13.4) it eventually stopped asking me.

But to get to System Preferences and out of the iCloud Pref pane click on the button that looks like a grid of dots, as below.

[image: Red arrow points to button to click]